# While Sculpting how do I stop the Rotate Brush from using the Origin?

Tags: sculpting

First time posting a question.  Been using blender and poking around the exchange here for answers and usually find what I am looking for.  This time not so much.

Currently I am working on a human Finger and tried to follow the steps laid out in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Yt1ToAqDxY

Everything goes fine until I hit the 1:20 mark.  I set up the mask, set the pivot point, move it out but when attempting to use the rotate brush in Sculpt mode it only rotates from the origin, not the Set Pivot Point. (Origin, Unmasked, Mask Border, Etc)

I should also mention I did run across this:

https://developer.blender.org/T70926

The issue being described at the end seems very similar to the issue I am seeing.

[image: Pivot Point Set]
[image: Rotating from Origin]

---

Update.

I Have started a new blend file for testing.  Here is the desired behavior in action:

[image: Setting a pivot point in Sculpt mode:]

Here is the desired Result:

[image: Proper Rotation]

Here is the undesired behavior:

[image: Same Set Up]

It might be difficult to see but the Line that is showing the pivot point is headed back to the world origin instead of at the gimbal pictured above.

[image: Different Result]

Actually the more I test things out the more I realize I am experiencing exactly the same behavior that I see in the ticket on the developer board and it is still labelled as a known bug.

Is there a version of blender where this behavior isnt an issue?

Comment: I see no bug there ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

After running multiple tests on several different files I found an answer to my original question.

Apparently there is still an issue with Box Masks and possibly enabling mirroring while sculpting and using the rotate brush as seen on the developer link I found earlier:

https://developer.blender.org/T70926

Here is an example of proper rotation functionality with a hand painted mask and no mirror not enabled using mask border as the rotation point:
[image: Proper Pivot]

Now here is an example of the functionality breaking when using box mask:

[image: Wrong Pivot]

As you can see in the second image the pivot stays fixed at its original position and will not move the border of the mask.

To fix this issue simply clearing and hand painting a mask didn't seem to work.  However exporting the mesh then reimporting it into a new scene seems to have reset something and now the rotation functionality is working as expected again.

Answer (score 1):

H i ,welcome to bse , in sculpt mode , Hit "DOT" ( . ) on your keyboard and whether choose 3d cursor or median point (which is the origin of geometry ) and 3d cursor's location can be changed with Shift + right click , or hit N > side view > view tab
(don't forget to accept the answerrr ;)
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

Can you explain what your keyboard shortcuts do just in case we have a I different set up?  I have tried to perform the the keyboard shortcuts you described but nothing is happening.  No radial menu appears etc.

Comment: Uh its actually called "period" and its pretty common in blender , i'll update the answer so you can find the key

Comment: Thank you again Hamed, i appreciate you taking time out of your day to reply.  Follow up question for you, is your answer specific to sculpt mode?

I just realized after rereading your response that you mention the 3d Cursor but in sculpt mode I don't see a cursor only the brush.

Also I am going to update my original question with a few more screenshots to demonstrate my issue.

Comment: 3d cursor is always present but you cant see it when youre in sculpt mode tab , you can in object mode place your 3d cursor by activating snap to face , then hit ctrl + tab and go to sculpt mode inside object mode tab then youll have your cursor

Comment: Thanks for that bit of info!

I used it on one of the practice meshes and the gimbal did indeed show up right where I left the cursor in edit mode.

I am sure that will come in handy.

That said when I tried to repeat that same process, the new unmasked portion of my mesh started rotating around origin instead of the new pivot point again.

I may have found a work around but want to test it a bit more before posting here.

Thanks

Comment: @JasonMohamed Try to recalculate normals by Shift + n  in edit mode and apply rotation and scale by ctrl + a in object mode to prevent any of those happens